# How to remove the attributes in an object in react-native (Need to shown only the values)

Tags: javascript, react-native

My object looks like below structure. How can I remove the below mentioned three lines

```
data: [
    { id: 1, name: Mike, city: philps, state: New York, _id:'323232323'},
    { id: 2, name: Steve, city: Square, state: Chicago, _id:'32324444'},
    { id: 3, name: Jhon, city: market, state: New York, _id:'323277777'},

    {id: '{"name":"test","email":""}',name: Jhon, city: market, state: New York} //need to remove this

    { id: 4, name: philps, city: booket, state: Texas, _id:'32328888'},
    { id: 5, name: smith, city: brookfield, state: Florida, _id:'32329999'},
    { id: 6, name: Broom, city: old street, state: Florida, _id:'3230000'},

    {id: '{"name":"test","email":""}',name: Broom, city: old street, state: Florida} //need to remove this

    {id: '{"name":"test","email":""}',name: smith, city: brookfield, state: Florida} //need to remove this
]
```

Comment: Probably you could use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove not [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) type of `id` ones. But this is just a guess of the logic what you need.

Comment: How should be the strategy to remove it? It's dynamically? You want to remove all with id numeric?

Comment: I need it to remove dynamically with id numeric values and cities need to be shown in UI

Answer (score 0):

Simple in one line

```js
let data = [
    { id: 1, name: "A"},
    { id: 2, name: "B"},
    {id: {"name":"test","email":""},name: "C"} //need to remove this

   
];

data = data.filter(item => Number.isInteger(item.id));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Above returns empty value

Comment: Look, I updated the answer with a snippet. It works. Your sample json has wrong sintaxis, so I removed unnecessary data, but it's the same

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data.filter(item => item.id === '{"name":"test","email":""}');
```